# issue in shell script inside groovy which is passing two different types of parameters

Tags: git, shell, unix, jenkins, groovy

A overview of the scenario: i want a dictionary/map which will have this type of structure:

it's key will be: a directory name

it's value will be: the total number of changes of files for that dir

i have a list which has the directory names. [ms_dir] is that list
Now, I am writing a groovy script.inside it, i'm trying to run a shell and assign it to a value. i want to do the following using the shell:

1. it takes a git diff of a directory which im passing it as a variable into the shell script
2. for that directory it will extract the total number of changes occured in each directory
   i am running this over a loop for a couple of directories which is stored in [ms_dir]

```
[ms_dir] = [aws_app1_service, aws_app2_service, aws_app3_service, aws_app4_service]
def changed_no = [:]
for (int i = 0; i< ms_dir.size();i++){
  println "${ms_dir[i]}"
  changed_no["${ms_dir[i]}"] = []
  change_value = sh '''git diff --name-status HEAD^ HEAD ${ms_dir[i]} | cut -d'/' -f1 | sort |  uniq -c | awk '{print $1}' '''
  changed_no["ms_dir[i]"].add("$value")
  println "${changed_no}"
}
println "total number of changes in each dir: ${changed_no}"
```

the problem i'm facing here is that due to different form of parameters ${ms_dir[i]} and {print $1} the shll inside the groovy is not working.
If i use triple or double quotes, it is not passing ${ms_dir[i]} value. Below is that output. As you can see it is giving the values of each directories and not the one that is looping

```
2020-07-22 21:24:08.092 | . aws_app1_service
[Pipeline] sh
2020-07-22 21:24:08.375 | . + git diff --name-status 'HEAD^' HEAD
2020-07-22 21:24:08.375 | . + cut -d/ -f1
2020-07-22 21:24:08.375 | . + sort
2020-07-22 21:24:08.375 | . + uniq -c
2020-07-22 21:24:08.375 | . + awk '{print $1}'
2020-07-22 21:24:08.375 | . 2
2020-07-22 21:24:08.375 | . 4
2020-07-22 21:24:08.375 | . 1
2020-07-22 21:24:08.375 | . 2
```

and when im using single quotes, it is throwing DSL error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method ' -f1 | sort |  uniq -c | awk ' found among steps [ArtifactoryGradleBuild, MavenDescriptorStep, addInteractivePromotion,
 ansiColor, archive, artifactoryDistributeBuild, artifactoryDownload, artifactoryEditProps, artifactoryMavenBuild, artifactoryNpmInstall, artifactoryNpmPublish, artifactoryPromoteBuild, 
artifactoryUpload, bat, build, catchError, checkout, collectEnv, conanAddRemote, conanAddUser, 
deleteDir, deployArtifacts, dir, dockerFingerprintFrom, dockerFingerprintRun, dockerPullStep, dockerPushStep, echo, emailext, emailextrecipients, envVarsForTool, error, fileExists, 
findBuildScans, findFiles, getArtifactoryServer, getContext, git, httpRequest,
 initConanClient, input,
```

Please let me know how to sort out this shell part. Is there any way i can both include ${ms_dir[i]} as a groovy variable and {print $1} as shell parameter

Comment: Why `[ms_dir] = [...` and not `ms_dir = [...`

Answer (score 1):

## Command use

Most of the commands you're sending to the shell can be accmplished in Groovy. e.g. sort, unique and the awk print. It apears you only need to execute the git command. See the example below for one way to accomplish this. An alternative would be to pipe results of your git comand into the Groovy script.

The script you provided doesn't compile for me, and your command exeution looks wrong. As I don't understand your code I'll show you how I'd accomplish the task.

## Listing staged changes for tracked files in given sub-dirs

It sounds like you want a map of staged tracked files for each directory. If that's not what you need then change the `cmd` collection to match the command you're trying to execute.

That's implemented like this:

```
def ms_dir = [
  'aws_app1_service',
  'aws_app2_service',
  'aws_app3_service',
  'aws_app4_service'
]

def cmd = ['git', 'status', '--untracked=no', '--short']
def changes = cmd.execute().text

def dirChangeCounts = [:]
ms_dir.each {
  dirChangeCounts[it] = 0
}

changes.eachLine { change ->
  def resultLineParts = change.split( "[ ]+|[/]" )
  dirChanged = resultLineParts[1]
  if ( ms_dir.contains( dirChanged ) ) {
    dirChangeCounts[ dirChanged ]++
  }
}

dirChangeCounts.each { dirName, count ->
  suffix = count == 1 ? ' ' : 's'
  printf '%3d staged change%s in %s\n', count, suffix, dirName
}
```

### Results

Running the above script on my test repository gives this output:

```
  1 staged change  in aws_app1_service
  4 staged changes in aws_app2_service
  3 staged changes in aws_app3_service
  9 staged changes in aws_app4_service
```